# How many bits of entropy would I get from 300 coin tosses?

Tags: entropy

Bonus question, what is the formula to calculate this?

Comment: If it's an unbiased coin, you get one bit per toss. Since Shannon entropy is additive for independent events, you get 300 bits total. (This assumes that you toss 300 times, not that you toss 300 indistinguishable coins together)

Comment: The formula is $n$ bits of entropy for $n$ coin tosses with a fair coin.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Re: fair coin, does is really matter when each toss varies in rotational speed and length of time it rotates?

Comment: @user21767, "fair coin" refers to a coin that has an even chance of turning up heads or tails, one that shows no bias over multiple flips.  It encompasses the entire process of flipping a coin, including rotations, speed, wind, gravity, whatever; and it is considered fair only if the outcome is statistically unpredictable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $X\colon\;\Omega\to\Sigma$ be a random source that emits symbols from a finite alphabet $\Sigma$. Write $p_\sigma:=\Pr[X=\sigma]$ for the probability that $\sigma$ is emitted. Then, the entropy $H(X)$ of $X$ is defined as
$$H(X) = -\sum_{\sigma\in\Sigma}p_\sigma\log_2p_\sigma\text.$$
(If $p_\sigma$ is $0$, one uses the convention $p_\sigma\log_2p_\sigma=0$.)

In this case, $\Sigma=\{0,1\}^{300}$, hence $\lvert\Sigma\rvert=2^{300}$, and, assuming the coin is fair, all $p_\sigma$ are equal to $1/\lvert\Sigma\rvert=2^{-300}$. Therefore:
$$H(X)=-\sum_{\sigma\in\Sigma}p_\sigma\log_2p_\sigma=-\lvert\Sigma\rvert\cdot2^{-300}(-300)=300\text,$$
which is just what one would intuitively expect from 300 random bits.

---

Note: One could also repeatedly apply the fact that, for *independent* random variables $X\colon\;\Omega\to\Sigma_1$ and $Y\colon\;\Omega\to\Sigma_2$, their combined entropy — that is, the entropy of
$$X\times Y\colon\;\Omega^2\to\Sigma_1\times\Sigma_2,\;(\omega_1,\omega_2)\mapsto(X(\omega_1),Y(\omega_2))$$
in the product space — is $$H(X\times Y)=H(X)+H(Y)\text,$$
to $X\colon\;\Omega\to\{0,1\}$ uniformly distributed.

Comment: This seems like an overly complicated / formalised answer to a very simple problem. Sure, it's correct, but I find it questionable if it helps the understanding of the matter.

Comment: Is that Klingon? +1 for trying. Edit: I can't +1, not enough rep, sorry.

Comment: It *is* overly complicated when trying to *understand* entropy, no doubt, but formally *proving* something about entropy requires the *definition* of entropy. Besides that, @user21767 specifically asked for the formula.

Comment: Yeah, I'm the OP, if you look at the question it's a given that I won't be able to understand this answer. Thanks anyway, hopefully other users will upvote you.

Comment: Great answer! You may want to add that $|\Sigma| = 2^{300}$ so no one gets lost.

Comment: @yyyyyyy Part of answering any question is understanding the audience involved.  The voice you use to speak with is going to vary depending on who's listening.  Someone that asks a very simple (but important) question like the above is very unlikely to understand a formal mathematical definition of entropy.  (And as noted by user21767 this was indeed the case).

Comment: @SteveSether As I wrote above, this is the *formal* answer to the question. If you deem it unhelpful, feel free to create a better one!

Comment: @yyyyyyy Unfortunately I'm a poor translator on this particular subject.  While I certainly understand why coin flips are additive for entropy, I don't understand your formal mathematical write up to be able to translate it to be comprehensible to a lay audience.